# How can i resize root partion using gparted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

How to extend this unallocated size to the root partition.
i tried to resize it by right click on /dev/sda7 and click resize but not showing any space to extend

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64084/discussion-on-question-by-stack-user-how-can-i-resize-root-partion-using-gparted).

Answer (score 0):

The allocated space needs contiguously come after the /dev/sda7 partition. I would right click on the /dev/sda7 partition and go to resize and move and drag the /dev/sda7 partition (that's between the resize arrows) so that it's before the gray space and that the gray space comes after. If it takes awhile to move, let it do it's thing and after it's moved, as long as the unallocated space is AFTER the /dev/sda7 partition, you should now be able to extend the partition. If that doesn't work, please let me know because I spent several hours when I had this problem a couple months ago.

Comment: 1) I don't think grub bios can be moved without causing issues. 2) having both OS's boot in same mode will greatly simplify his boot procedure, since grub can launch both if they re in the same mode

Comment: i'm afraid friend that affect windows because i have a very important data

Comment: Yeah the offset changing can change how Windows boots. I think that you can go into your Windows installation disk if you have one or a repair disk and automatically search and fix problems and that should fix it but if you don't want to risk it, then maybe you could convert disk to dynamic disk and I think that works for non-contiguous space. If not, then I'm sorry I don't know what else to say.